# SQL Server: best way to insert "mm/dd/yyyy" into a "date" or "datatime2" column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-insert

I have a bunch of values in the form of `mm/dd/yyyy` stored in a CSV. An example is `06/26/2017`.  What I found was that I could NOT insert it into a column declared as `date` or `datetime2` type.  What I CAN do is to modify that (empty) column to `varchar` first, then insert.

However at this point, after insertion as varchars, how can I convert this column to "date" or "datatime2"?

Attempting to set system-wide format doesn't work:

```
sql> SET DATEFORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy'
[2019-03-31 09:42:04] [S0001][2741] SET DATEFORMAT date order 'mm/dd/yyyy' is invalid.
```

Comment: Try `SET DATEFORMAT mdy`.

Comment: Load the data into a staging table where all columns are strings and do the conversions in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If the column's data type is `date` then convert the string to `date` with:

```
convert(date, '03/31/2019', 101)
```

and then insert it.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1c1b83bd221e775324631f8a48aaa729).
Read more about [convert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  
**Edit**:
Create a varchar column and a date column. Insert the values inside the varchar column and when the process finishes, update the date column by converting each value to a date, like:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET datecolumn = convert(date, varcharcolumn, 101)
```

After that you can remove the varchar column.

Comment: Hey, the issue is I can't insert into a date/datetime2 column with those values.  All I can do is to insert those values into a varchar column first.  Is this expected?

Comment: You will not insert these values as they are. You will convert them to date and then insert them.

Comment: I understand that - however these are string literals in a CSV file.  Is there a way to bulk upload such a file & convert on the fly?

Comment: Ok, I missed that you want to directly insert them from a csv.  See my edited answer